# How to know when the user is offline?

Tags: android, firebase

I'm developing a messenging app, based on firebase's friendlychat app. How can I implement a method that checks if I'm online/offline, and send the status to my chat partner, so he/she can see if I'm online or not. Is it possible with firebase, or do I need to set up an own server, which pings my device? I want a device to be indicated "offline" when the app is killed, or there is no internet connection, or the screen is off for more than 5 minutes
Be indicated "online", when there is internet connection and the app is running, but not in foreground, and the screen is either on, or off for less than 5 minutes
And finally, be indicated "in app" when net is connected, screen is on, and app is in foreground 
Is this possible?

Comment: There is an example of precisely that in the Firebase documentation. Rather than repeating it here, I'll link you to it: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-sample